# move image using java script and html css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to move a image in a path using js and html.
is that doable?

please check the image to get better idea about my question. are there any example codes or libraries? so I can study and edit to match into my case.[image: tm]

Comment: for simple programming with the canvas i can recommend you the p5js library because its very beginner friendly. For the path you need probably some cos/sin function but im not an expert in maths.

Comment: I think this would be even possible with pure css animations. Depends on how much interactivity by the users you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to approach this problem.

1. Modify html image css styling via javascript.

   - [add css styling via javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp).
   - styling to move/rotate : `transform: translate(20px,10px) rotate(0.5turn);`
2. change styling using pure css animations `@keyframes` [more here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)
3. Display stuff on `<canvas>` element via javascript [more here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp)
4. Animated svg, or svg with css animation.
5. Inline svg animated via javascript or css.

I am  for now just going to demonstrate the svg approach.

## SVG approach (no javascript)

My preferred approach would be to create a svg containing multiple images, and then animate it. The bellow example is just using circle objects, but images should work too using `<image href="">`.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <path id="movepath" d="M 5 5 C 10 10, 20 10, 25 5" stroke="#aaa" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
    <circle cx=5 cy=5 r=2 fill="#aaa"/>
    <circle cx=25 cy=5 r=2 fill="#aaa"/>
    <circle r=1.5 fill="#000">
        <animateMotion dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite">
            <mpath xlink:href="#movepath"/>
        </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I had understood your question, but I try to answer you.
If I should to do this, "move rocket from earth to sun" I would do it like this:

I'll create 3 img.

```
img rocket;
img earth; 
img sun;
```

With CSS I will set the Rocket img movement from img earth to sun. Html is not request.